# 30 minutes ago time format in Solaris

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I am writing the below command for 1 hour ago in Solaris format.

```
date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S -M  "1 hour ago"
```

But I need half hour (30 minutes) ago format in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Linux, this should work if run in bash:

```
date --date=@$((`date +%s`-1800))
```

(I tested it on Solaris 11 using gdate instead of date.  I don't have a Linux box booted right now.)

Answer (score 0):

Solaris 10 `date` command doesn't support the `-M` flag which is a GNU date extension.

An alternative is to use `perl`.

Here is how to get one hour ago:

```
perl -e 'my ($y,$m,$d,$H,$M,$S)=(localtime(time-3600))[5,4,3,2,1,0];
    printf "%04d-%02d-%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$y+1900,$m+1,$d,$H,$M,$S;'
```

and half-an-hour ago:

```
perl -e 'my ($y,$m,$d,$H,$M,$S)=(localtime(time-1800))[5,4,3,2,1,0];
    printf "%04d-%02d-%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$y+1900,$m+1,$d,$H,$M,$S;'
```

Edit: Using the POSIX Perl module, you can also do it this simpler way:

```
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime);
    print strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S\n", localtime(time-1800));'
```

Comment: Even simpler (using the `POSIX` module), as shown in [How can I find the current date minus seven days in Unix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475739/how-can-i-find-the-current-date-minus-seven-days-in-unix/29480300#29480300)