# How can I find the current date minus seven days in Unix?

Tags: unix, sh, ksh

I am trying to find the date that was seven days before today.

```
 CURRENT_DT=`date +"%F %T"`
 diff=$CURRENT_DT-7 
 echo $diff
```

I am trying stuff like the above to find the 7 days less than from current date. Could anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GNU `date` will to the math for you:

```
date --date "7 days ago"
```

Other version will require you to covert the current date into seconds since the UNIX epoch first, manually subtract 7 days' worth of seconds, and convert that back into the desired form. Consult the documentation for your version of `date` for details on how to convert to and from Unix timestamps. Here's an example using GNU `date` again:

```
x=$(date +%s)
x=$((x - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60))
date --date @$x
```

Comment: pday=7
CURRENT=`date +"%F %T" --date "$pday days ago"`
echo $CURRENT
how abt this

Comment: That's fine. The shell handles replacing `$pday` with 7, so `date` gets the same argument to `--date` either way.

Comment: Likewise, GNU date is unlikely to be installed on a *Unix* system (likely only Linux and constructs such as Cygwin).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple Perl script which (unlike the other examples) works with *Unix*:

```
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(ctime); printf "%s", ctime(time - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60));'
```

(Tested with Solaris 10, and a token Linux system, of course - with the caveat that Perl is not *necessarily* part of one's configuration, merely very likely).

Answer (score 2):

Adding this one for shells on OSX:

```
date -v-7d
> Tue Apr  3 15:16:31 EDT 2018
date
> Tue Apr 10 15:16:33 EDT 2018
```

Need that formated?

```
date -v-7d +%Y-%m-%d
> 2018-04-03
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ksh`'s `printf` can do time calculation:

```
$ printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n'
2015-04-07
$ printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T\n' '7 days ago'
2015-03-31
$
```

Comment: Interesting (I see it is a relatively new feature -- in the [ksh](http://www2.research.att.com/~astopen/man/man1/ksh.html) manual on  *[AST UNIX MANUAL](http://www2.research.att.com/~astopen/man/), but not in older versions as seen in [*nixDoc](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/ksh.1.html).  A quick check on a Debian system shows it as part of ksh93 (OP did not provide details).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used unix in a while but I found this in one of my scripts

```
echo `date +%s`-604800 | bc
```

Comment: what is this 604800000 am getting results like 823540175

Comment: @jcrshankar Oh whoops, a few extra zeros, it should be 604800

Comment: Tag says "Unix", but this example does not work with Solaris 10.  As a rule, *Unix* does not allow the `date` command to be used in this way.  Perl can do this, of course.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Ah, okay. I don't do much of Unix

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE=$(date --date "7 days ago" | awk '{print$1,$2,$3}')
echo "$DATE"
if [ -z "$(grep -i "$DATE" test.log)" ]; then
  exit 1
fi
sed -i "1,/$DATE/d" test.log
```

Comment: add some details please and elaborate why your solution works.